# C++ compiler error when running code (seg fault core dumped)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*
Animal cheapest(string type, Animal a[], int size) that returns the
cheapest animal in a of type type (that is, the cheapest cat or dog). 
Note: Assuming you’ve
filled in an array of Animals called shelter, calling cheapest from your 
main function would
look like
Animal inexpensive = cheapest(“Dog”, shelter, 20);
*/
struct Animal{
string name = "";
string gender = "";
int age = 0;
int price = 0;
string catOrDog = "";
};

Animal cheapest(string type, Animal a[], int size){
  int smallest = a[0].price;
  int indexOfSmallest = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
    if(a[i].price < smallest && a[i].catOrDog == type){
      indexOfSmallest = i;
    }
  }

  return a[indexOfSmallest];
 }

void printAnimal(Animal name){
  cout<< name.name <<endl;
}

int main(){

  Animal arr[1];

  Animal one;
  one.name = "Chad";
  one.gender = "Female";
  one.age = 2;
  one.price = 1500;
  one.catOrDog = "Dog";
  Animal two;
  two.name = "Brian";
  two.gender = "Female";
  two.age = 2;
  two.price = 1000;
  two.catOrDog = "Dog";

  arr[0] = one;
  arr[1] = two;

  Animal inexpensive = cheapest("Dog", arr, 2);

  printAnimal(inexpensive);

  return 0;
}
```

Segmentation Error when running code. From what I've googled, this usually happens when you are reading from a file but I am not reading from a file.
What is wrong with my code? This is the first time I've encountered a problem like this so I am completely blank

Answer (score 1):

You declare an array with *one* element:

```
Animal arr[1];
```

Then you access it out of bounds by storing *two* elements into it:

```
arr[0] = one;
arr[1] = two;
```

Only the first index (`0`) is valid.

You should consider using a `std::array` or `std::vector` rather than a C-style array, so you don't have to pass its size separately.